# Circular Memory Reference inside adapter

Tags: android

If I have a button inside a cell within a ListView, is it safe for the button’s onClickListener to hold a reference to it's parent view, or is it going to cause a cyclic reference?

Ex:

```
@Override
public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bkg_amex);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its going to be a cyclic reference, but that isn't the end of the world.  The garbage collector is a mark and sweep rather than a reference count implementation so it can catch circular references.